# Alter primary key sequence( 'Default' to 'Always') in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have created the below table in DB2. Since the sequence is `GENERATED BY DEFAULT`, the primary key can be inserted in table(as the primary key is added after table creation with alter) and there is chance of duplicate values. The solution is to create the sequence by using `GENERATED BY ALWAYS`. Now I have data in table and I want to alter it from `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` to `GENERATED BY ALWAYS`

```
  CREATE TABLE HW_COB.ILCCDS 
  ( 
                   CDS_IDENTITY FOR COLUMN CDSID NUMERIC(13, 0) GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( 
                   START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 
                   NO MINVALUE NO MAXVALUE 
                   NO CYCLE NO ORDER 
                   CACHE 20 ) ,

CODE_1 FOR COLUMN CDSCD1 CHAR(30),
CODE_2 FOR COLUMN CDSCD2 CHAR(30) );
ALTER TABLE HW_COB.ILCCDS ADD CONSTRAINT HW_COB.PK_CDS_IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY (CDS_IDENTITY);
```

Comment: `the primary key can be inserted with duplicate value` - no, I don't think it can. It may _try_ to do so if the user specifies the value but it will fail.

Comment: Then it's not a primary key, rather it's a simple identity column with no `unique` clause - I perhaps should have looked closer at the definition rather than the text :-) From memory, you have to drop the identity column then create another with the same name (generated always of course), with the start value as the previous max plus one. At least that's the case for DB2/z, I suspect DB2/LUW may be similar. Though I suspect you're using the former based on the uppercase and non-descriptive names.

Comment: @ paxdiablo I have edited my Insert scripts, as I create primary key for column   CDS_IDENTITY

Comment: I aslo recall that (for DB2/z at least) marking a column as primary wasn't enough. You also had to create the index for it separately. It's been about a year since I touched the mainframe and I'm gradually removing it all from my wetware but that seems to still be stored somewhere :-) Not enough certainty to make it an answer but it may help nonetheless.

Comment: Do you think an index is to be created for primary key. :)

Comment: That's my recollection although, as mentioned, I'm gradually forgetting the pain :-) I _could_ be wrong, it wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: DB2 for i at least creates the needed index over the specified primary key. I'd be shocked that DB2 for z/OS wouldn't do so.  The OP doesn't mention the platform.  This [doc](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/zosbasics/com.ibm.db2z.doc.intro/db2z_keys.html) seems to indicate that DB2 for z/OS also automatically creates the needed index

Comment: If you look closely, you'll see FOR COLUMN syntax.  This indicates DB2 for i.  On IBM i, DB2 is an integral feature of the OS.  But the OS generally limits names of objects and columns to 10 characters.  The first name is the DB2-length name, and the FOR COLUMN clause defines the system name.  Either name can be used in SQL statements, or in other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Finally got the alter as :

ALTER TABLE HW_COB.ILCCDS ALTER COLUMN CDS_IDENTITY SET GENERATED ALWAYS;